# Calculating the ORs and 95% CI for a GEE exchangeable model

Tags: r

I have generated a GEE model with an exchangeable correlation structure, repeating participant ID, binary response variable, and 1 binary covariate. I am able to determine the estimate and p-value, however when I go to calculate the ODDs ratio and 95% confidence interval the code errors:

"Error in summ$coefficients[, "Std. Error", drop = FALSE] :   subscript out of bounds"

Could you please assist me in converting the estimate into an ODDs ratio and 95% CI?

```
gee_chills <- gee(status ~ chills, data = dat, id = participant_id, family = binomial(link = "logit"), corstr = "exchangeable")
exp(cbind(OR = coef(gee_chills), confint(gee_chills)))
```

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Naive S.E.    Naive z Robust S.E.   Robust z
(Intercept) -3.571655  0.1418610 -25.177136   0.1429035 -24.993476
chills1      1.817496  0.5032777   3.611318   0.5088764   3.571586
```